# Vuex getter not updating on state changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I can't get a vuex getter to update, when a state object changes.
I'm trying to get a vuex getter to return a total sum of the values in a state object, with a reduce function.

```
// Mutation
state.shippingFees[method.sellerId] = method.fee; // state.shippingFees = { 1: 1900 }; etc.

// Getter
totalShippingFees: state => Object.values(state.shippingFees).reduce((total, fee) => total + fee, 0)
```

After setting a shipping fee key-value pair in the state.shippingFees object, the getter still just returns 0.

Comment: The mutation should be a function call, here you're simply updating the state which is not allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method

Hence the way you are updating above object it is not reactive. Hence your values are not updated in the getter. To know more about vue reactivity read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

For making it reactive you need to use $set or object.assign

Update your mutation as below =>

```
Vue.$set(state.shippingFees,method.sellerId,method.fee);
```

Answer (score 5):

Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion

Use `Vue.set(state.shippingFees, method.sellerId, method.fee)`

More details [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the official documentation [Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in Vue. You can't change the array elements by index. There is to ways to achieve the same with reactivity as given below

```js
state.shippingFees.splice(index, 1, val) 
//using the splice method, replace the element at index
```

or. alternatively, you can use

```js
Vue.set(state.shippingFees, index , val)

//You can also use the vm.$set instance method, which is an alias for the global Vue.set method
vm.$set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

Vue can not detect the change when you directly update the item using the index, or modify the array length property.